# Does $\mathbb{R}$ have a partite subbase?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, partitions, hypergraph

If $X\neq \varnothing$ is a set we say that ${\frak P} \subseteq {\cal P}(X)$ is a *partition* of $X$ if

1. $\bigcup{\frak P} = X$, and
2. $P\neq Q \in {\frak P} \implies P\cap Q = \varnothing$.

Let $H = (V,E)$ be a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) with $V \neq \varnothing$ and $\bigcup E = V$. A partition ${\frak P}$ of $V$ is said to be *splitting* if  for all $e\in E$ and $P \in {\frak P}$ we have $|e \cap P| = 1$, and we call such a hypergraph admitting a splitting partition *partite*.

It is easy to see that every edge in a partite hypergraph $H$ has the same cardinality $\kappa$, and that $\kappa$ is also the cardinality of every splitting partition of $H$.

Let $\tau$ be the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$. It is easy to see that $(\mathbb{R}, \tau\setminus\{\varnothing\})$ cannot have a splitting partition since $\mathbb{R} \in \tau$.

**Question.** Is there a [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase) ${\cal S}\subseteq (\tau\setminus\{\varnothing\})$ such that $(\mathbb{R}, {\cal S})$ is partite?

Comment: The restriction $X\neq\emptyset$ is non-standard, nevertheless it is usual to assume that *components* of a partition are nonempty. For instance for $X=\{1,2,3\}$ you currently allow both $\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$ and $\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2,3\}\}$ as distinct partitions. Probably you want to remove $X\neq\emptyset$, and add $P\in\mathfrak{P}$ $\Rightarrow$ $P\neq\emptyset$ in the axioms.

Comment: A near miss: $\mathcal S$ is all open intervals of length $1$, and $\mathfrak{P}$ is all shifts of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: May I ask what the motivation for your question is? and why do you ask for a subbase and not for a base?

Comment: A base would contain (an infinite chain of) sets nested by inclusion, but a partite hypergraph has no pair of nested edges.

Comment: If it can help, it is not too difficult to see that any $P$ in a possible $\mathfrak P$ would be closed discrete, and there would be for all $[-M,M]$ an $\varepsilon>0$ (depending only on $M$) such that the distance between two points of $P\cap [-M,M]$ would be at least $\varepsilon$ (the distance between two consecutive points of $P$ is locally bounded below, uniformly in $P$).

Comment: @JanKyncl That's right - so first I was wondering whether ${\mathbb R}$ had a subbase without nested elements and then found out this to be true, so I could turn towards partiteness

Comment: @RamirodelaVega Thanks for your question about the motivation. My questions often arise out of some playfulness. In this case it happened this way. I was reading [this article](https://math.berkeley.edu/~linbo/documents/CSS/RyserConjecture.pdf) about Ryser's conjecture and wondered whether the concept of "partiteness" that appears on slide 7 can be applied to topological spaces. I quickly realized that nestedness of open sets posed a problem - therefore the question about a subbase